# PK and Columnstore on same columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, I have a table with 7 columns. The first 6 (almost all numbers) are used to uniquely identify the percentage held in the 7th. There are over 46M rows, and the table is updated once per day according to a set of rules. The update does massive delete and inserts as needed.

In this kind of scenario, what combination of PK and columnstore index would I need? A clustered PK on the first 6 columns only? Both a PK and columnstore?

What would be the pros and cons of having both (or only one) PK and CSI? Which one should be clustered? I have little CSI experience, thus the question. I want to learn how they combine effectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the data is key values, I would with a clustered index on the key.

Then evaluate adding a Non-Clustered Columnstore index if you have common queries that need to scan large numbers of rows.  This a simple assesment of whether the cost of building the NCCI is worth the reduction in cost of the queries that access it.